# Higher kinded type's flatMap return type is resolved to base Iterable instead of the higher kinded type itself

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I have the following code:

```
  case class Foo[+CC[A] <: Iterable[A]](foo: CC[Int])
  
  def customReduce[CC1[A] <: Iterable[A], CC2[A] <: Iterable[A]](foos: CC1[Foo[CC2]]): Foo[CC1] =
    Foo(foos.flatMap(_.foo))
  
  println(customReduce(Seq(Foo(Seq(1)))))
```

Foo is a type that takes any collection type. When I do customReduce, calling `foos.flatMap` should return the same type as foos, which is `CC1[Foo[CC2]]`, but the compiler resolves it to the base `Iterable` and complains:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Iterable[Int]
 required: CC1[Int]
```

Why does this happen and how can I resolve this?

---

EDIT: it appears that after Iterable extends IterableOps, the CC type is fixed to Itearble. How can I make the above code work?

Comment: Do you really need to support any collection type? Making code that works generically for any collection is a pain and is different in `2.13+` and `2.12-` _(so you may want to include in the question which is your **Scala** version)_ - I would just use concrete types or use better abstractions like `Monad` from **cats**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala 2.13 you can use `scala.collection.Factory`

```
def customReduce[CC1[A] <: Iterable[A], CC2[A] <: Iterable[A]](foos: CC1[Foo[CC2]])(implicit 
  factory: Factory[Int, CC1[Int]]
): Foo[CC1] = Foo(foos.flatMap(_.foo).to(factory))


println(customReduce(Seq(Foo(Seq(1))))) // Foo(List(1))
```

Comment: Choosing this as a correct answer although I found the answer to the original question. This requires an additional collection to be created btw.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found myself:

Since `flatMap` is from IterableOps and `Foo::foo` requires Iterable, I need to declare CC1 as the compound type of `IterableOps` and `Iterable`:

```
def customReduce[CC1[A] <: Iterable[A] with IterableOps[A, CC1, CC1[A]], CC2[A] <: Iterable[A]](foos: CC1[Foo[CC2]]): Foo[CC1] =
    Foo(foos.flatMap(_.foo))
```

Now flatMap correctly resolves to CC1 thanks to `IterableOps.flatMap` signature that returns original CC